# How to speed up the Android Emulator in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: android, emulation

On Ubuntu 12.10, Android Emulator is too slow, how can I speed it up?

I installed SDK with `adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219`.

I tried to use host GPU and get some more speed, but when I launch it, there is still some lagging.

Comment: I know this is an old question.. but for anyone who has this problem on linux, check this out, it worked for me: http://techtach.com/2014/05/boost-android-emulator-performanceon-linux-speeding-up-android-emulator-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

This is not Ubuntu specific. The Android SDK's speed is terrible.
That's not a flamebait or anything, it's sadly... a fact.

There is an alternative.
**Genymotion** - https://www.genymotion.com/

It provides a fast phone, phone/tablet, or tablet for all your needs, with a blazing fast speed. It's not native, runs on x86 Android. So while it won't replace "real testing", it is the best way to develop. It is only free for personal use though, keep that in mind.

The installation instructions change with time, so I did not copy those out.
Genymotion is not the only option of course, it's just the one I have always been using.
You could also simply install an x86 image of Android into Virtualbox.
But Genymotion has become pretty much the industry standard - as far as I know.

v2 - 2016.

Comment: no thanks i will not change my way with using ubuntu for some speed :P

Comment: You are not using Ubuntu, you are using a qemu by Google, which emulates arm/x86 very, very slowly. Same way, just a faster one. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to AndroVM. This should be an accepted answer!

Comment: It seems that AndroVM is no longer being maintained. The website redirects to GenyMotion which is payed. The GitHub profile http://github.com/androvm is abandoned.

Comment: @FabianStreitel You are right and wrong. AndroVM indeed is now Genymotion. But Genymotion IS free! Just register on the site, and you can use the client. Of course, if you are a developer, you would have to pay - but today, you can also just use an Android x86 image for example if you want to test, but also you are on a tight budget. **For home use, Genymotion is the best choice.** You can install Play Store, you can play games, do everything.

Comment: Ah I see, the personal edition is a bit hidden on their website. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly simple, just enable kvm acceleration in these steps (linux only):

1. create x86 image of phone (CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86))
2. pass these arguments:

   ```
    -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm
   ```

That's it pretty much (lets not bother with gpu acceleration and other fancy stuff).
When compared with classic arm version, it speeds it up tenfold.

This should be easy to setup with android studio, just go into avd manager, create x86 device and then in main menu go to Run -> Edit configuration -> Emulator (tab) -> aditional command line parameters: "-qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm".

Comment: The documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html says that the -m must match the emulator memory size, so that might be something to watch out for when using these flags e.g. in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

@Hany Alsamman: If you have a CPU of Intel supporting Virtual Technology you can try to install Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager as well as the plugin for your Android AVD. This will really speed your Emulator up. 
The Virtual Technology must be enabled in BIOS section. I think you can follow the steps in this post

http://hintdesk.com/android-how-to-speed-up-android-emulator/

It's for Windows but the steps are all relevant to setup/configuration things, not really specific for Windows.

Comment: thanks , maybe it's good solution for me but if you are on old pc maybe not helpful

Comment: Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager(HAXM) doesn't work on linux.